# CollectionVIew dynamic calculation width, item display is incomplete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

The `UICollectionView` uses the calculated item attribute (estimatedItemSize) to calculate the width of the item and the layout of the Masonry used by `UICollectionViewCell.m`. As a result, the last Item cannot be pulled and the display is incomplete. Modifying contentInset has no effect.

Directly fixed item size can be completely displayed, guessing that the dynamic calculation does not calculate the width.

[image]
[image]

## Code:

MainViewController:

[image]

HeaderCollectionView:

[image]

HeaderViewCell:

[image]

Comment: No need to repeat the question in Simplified Chinese. Also, where is your code?

Comment: Copy/paste code, don't post screenshot of them.